# how can i automate enabling of onenote in msoffice 2016 using vbscript

Tags: vbscript

I need to automate below steps via vbscript. please anybody help me.

1. Kill all MS Office process (need to display a popup message before closing all MS office application)
2. Open control panelprogram and features-> right click MS Office.
3. Select Add or remove features.
4. Select the dropdown in Microsoft Onenote and select Run all from My computer and click continue.

Thanks
Jerin

Answer (score 0):

You're  better of using powershell or even plain old batch commands, as vbs is a very old language.

For killing office process, run:

> Taskkill /IM winword.exe /F
>   Taskkill /IM excel.exe /F

You will need administrator privileges for this.

For listing all features, run:

> DISM /online /get-features /format:table

For enabling a feature, run:

> DISM /online /enable-feature /featurename:[feature name]

From:
[Raymond](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/add-or-remove-windows-features-through-the-command-prompt/)
See also [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/enable-or-disable-windows-features-using-dism#to-enable-windows-features)

As for the message to user, see [this](https://mcpmag.com/articles/2016/06/09/display-gui-message-boxes-in-powershell.aspx?m=1).

Comment: the above command not listing msoffice add on . It displaying only below items.OEMHelpCustomization
CorporationHelpCustomization
SimpleTCP
SNMP
WMISnmpProvider
TelnetServer
TelnetClient
WindowsGadgetPlatform
InboxGames
More Games
Solitaire

Comment: Sorry, didn't see you were asking about office addons. For enabling office features, use the OCT tool, see: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/2ea12494-b6c0-46de-b2c6-888a72395b7b/addremove-features-in-office-2010-with-modify?forum=officesetupdeployprevious